# Selecting an Excel worksheet using a variable

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have a variable called content which contains a worksheets name. I want the program to be able to find this worksheet inside my Excel file. I would normally accomplish this by doing this:

```
 Dim xlapp As Excel.Application
 Dim xlworkbook As Excel.Workbook
 Dim xlworksheet As Excel.Worksheet

 xlapp = New Excel.Application
 xlworkbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("F:\ComputerScience\Program\Scouts.xlsx")
 xlworksheet = xlworkbook.Worksheets("Member")
```

I've changed it to include a for loop to try to find the workbook then select it:

```
xlapp = New Excel.Application
xlworkbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("F:\Computer Science\Program\Scouts.xlsx")
For Each xlworksheet In xlworkbook.Worksheets
    xlworksheet(content).select
Next
```

But this hasn't worked. So how do I get my program to find the worksheet and select it which shares the same name as the variable content?

Comment: xlworksheet = xlworkbook.Worksheets(content)

Comment: Why do you need the for loop? The only reason I could see would be to first check if that worksheet exists before setting it to a variable, which would require an If statement inside your for loop...     What is inside your current for loop doesn't make much sense.

Comment: In the end I didn't need a for loop and the code I posted before worked. I thought I needed the for loop to search though each spreadsheet.

Comment: Have you tried this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29166285/vba-opening-a-worksheet-by-variable-name]